# What are the most optimal ways to utilize reference images?

Tags: import, image

I find the standard Background Images too restricted and I would like to know what are the best ways to use and fine-tune the Image Empties, Import Image as Plane and others.

Comment: Hi. Please only ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask as many questions as you need, but as separate posts.

Comment: Having played around with image empties in the past, I've found that (for me) background images really work just as well, and with less clutter in the viewport. Perhaps if you can't find convenient blueprint-style references, image empties could have more utility, but really, imo going *solely* off perspective references is a last resort.